# Cannot find module 'ngx-cookie-service'

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-cookie-service

Iam using Angular 12,
I installed cookie by using:
**npm install --save ngx-cookie-service** 
in **app.module.ts** when I import **'CookieService'**
**import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';**
I got this error message:
**Cannot find module 'ngx-cookie-service' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)**
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like this is a reported [issue](https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service/issues/142) with ngx-cookie-service version 12.0.1. Downgrading to 12.0.0 seems to fix the problem for now.

```
npm install ngx-cookie-service@12.0.0
```

**-- UPDATE --** The issue is flagged as resolved with the release of version 12.0.2. Should be safe to install the latest now.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with version `13.1.2`!

I solved this by running an : `npm install`.